# selenium webdriver и амиго браузер

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Раз такие браузеры как амиго и яндекс браузер основаны на хромиуме, можно ли как то заставить selenium webdriver работать с ними? Интересует больше амиго браузер от майла.

> P.S. Если решили заминусовать, то не поленитесь и комментарий
>   оставить, почему вы это сделали, а так же ответьте на вопрос, есть ли
>   у вас опыт работы с селениумом, у меня достаточно большой опыт есть.

Answer (score 1):

Это невозможно, т.к. `WebDriver` для каждого браузера свой, selenium на текущий момент поддерживает только следующие браузеры:

- Mozilla GeckoDriver
- Google Chrome Driver
- Opera
- GhostDriver  (PhantomJS)
- Microsoft Edge Driver
- SafariDriver
- Windows Phone
- Selendroid
- ios-driver
- BlackBerry 10
- Appium
- CrossWalk
- QtWebDriver
- jBrowserDriver
- Winium.Desktop
- Winium.StoreApps
- Winium.StoreApps.CodedUi

Answer (score 0):

Яндекс браузер может работать с Selenium WebDriver, используя Operadriver. Нужно только указать путь к .exe Яндекс браузера.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\testselenium\\drivers\\operadriver.exe");
OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Yandex\\YandexBrowser\\Application\\browser.exe");
WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver(options);
driver.get("https://docs.seleniumhq.org");
```